# Anchor tag is not working inside Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="test">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="Aboutus.aspx">
                        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/background-image-top_banner.jpg"
                            ID="img" /></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

When I click on the Image in the gridview, it is not going to Aboutsus page? WHy don't the anchor tag work here?

Comment: is Aboutus.aspx in the same hierarchy as your page containing the gridview?

Comment: Yes, in the same hierarchy...

Comment: @Arghya:Edit1:It's just commandname. It doesn't have any implementation right now..

Comment: Can you remove the commandname attribute and try once?

Comment: Yes, I tried but no help..

Comment: Just use <img src="yourImageLocation" alt="some text if u want" /> instead of asp:imagebutton

Comment: I want to bind the image from database. So I can't use html img. I guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like this, to keep things simple

```
<a href="aboutus.aspx"><img src='<%# Eval("ImageSource") %>' /></a>
```

Or use src="your image location" , if that is static

Answer (score 1):

Dont use image button this will behave as an asp.net button, therefore  you have killed your link. Use asp:hyperlink instead

```
<asp:Hyperlink runat="server" Id="navAbtUs" NavigateUrl="AboutUs.aspx" ImageUrl="~/image/background-image-top_banner.jpg" ID="img" />
```

I'd also question why you are using a Gridview for this, you will have a column with repeated info.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this chagne image button to simple asp image

```
<a href="Aboutus.aspx">
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/background-image-top_banner.jpg"
                            ID="img" /></a>
```

Imagebutton is always creating problem for me,
so i always use link button and giving image between it

like

```
<asp:linkbutton id="id1" runat="server" ><img src='<Eval("Imagepath" >' /> </asp:linkbutton>
```

I know this is not appropriate answer, but i have faced problems with image button inside gridview and saw some other guys also face, so i suggested, this is a good alternate of image button

by the way why it is needed to put image button inside linkbutton, you can simply keep asp image if not want to use html image